# Digital filter algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, audio, signal-processing, wikipedia

I just found a fir algorithm on wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter

```
// if the size of NB_COEF = 2^n use a bit mask instead of the modulo (%)
// %=NB_COEF => &=(NB_COEF-1)
// pipe is a circular buffer

#define NB_COEF 16  // numbers of coefficients of the filter
double x_buffer[NB_COEF]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
double coef[NB_COEF]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int ptr_x_buffer=0;

double FiltreFIR(double x)
// x: Signal d'entrée
// y: Signal de sortie
{
  int n, y=0;
  x_buffer[ptr_x_buffer++] = x;
  ptr_x_buffer %= NB_COEF;

  for( n = (NB_COEF-1) ; n >= 0 ; n-- )
  {
    y += coef[n] * x_buffer[ptr_x_buffer++];
    ptr_x_buffer %= NB_COEF;
  }
  return(y);
}
```

-Can anybody tell me why do we need constantly to do this expression

```
ptr_x_buffer%= NB_COEFF.
```

Because for me it would mean the variable ptr_x_buffer always take the value 0 ?!
And it seems to me far from logic?!

And also can somebody explain to me the first comment about bit masking and modulo.

thank you in advance
:)

Comment: "Because for me it would mean the variable ptr_x_buffer always take the value 0" And why do you think that?

Answer (score 4):

It is used to ensure that the `ptr_x_buffer` is always a valid index inside the `x_buffer` array which is used as a cyclic buffer. Whenever `ptr_x_buffer` would overflow the array size it gets reset to `0`.

`ptr_x_buffer` gets incremented with each invocation of the function and on each iteration of the loop in `x_buffer[ptr_x_buffer++]`.

You could also replace the lines `ptr_x_buffer %= NB_COEF;` with this:

```
 if( ptr_x_buffer == NB_COEF )
     ptr_x_buffer = 0;
```

Or if you are sure that `NB_COEF` is a power of 2 you could mask them with a bitmask if as is stated in the comment already: `ptr_x_buffer &= NB_COEF-1;`.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, `x_buffer` is a circular buffer; `ptr_x_buffer` points to the current location in the buffer:

- `ptr_x_buffer++` increments `ptr_x_buffer`;
- `ptr_x_buffer %= NB_COEF` resets `ptr_x_buffer` to zero as soon as it reaches `NB_COEF`.

The comment suggests a modification of the code for certain values of `NB_COEF`. Whoever wrote that comments appears to have considered the suggested modification to be a performance improvement. However, it is highly doubtful that the change would lead to better performance and, therefore, the remark can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `ptr_x_buffer%=NB_COEFF` means that `ptr_x_buffer` is resetted modulo `NB_COEFF`. Therefore it is not "always 0" but the modulus with respect to division by 16. Therefore it is guaranteed that the array access `x_buffer[ptr_x_buffer]` always lies within the bounds `0..NB_COEFF-1`.

For powers of 2 the modulo operation can be replaced by a bitwise and with a mask of 2^n-1 (or N-1) where n is the log2 of your modulus.